# VBA Auto Unfilter ODBC Query Table in all Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to unfilter all worksheets before running macro, but this doesn't apply to tables that are coming from ODBC. This only works for my regular sheets with filters on.

Can someone help?

```
Sub UnfilterWS()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    For Each Wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    If Wks.AutoFilterMode Then
        Wks.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    Next Wks
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`WorkSheet.ShowallData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197246.aspx):

```
...
For Each Wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Wks.ShowAllData
Next Wks
...
```